# ng-style and javascript object with the same named properties

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

How do you guys deal with the situation like this:

```
<div ng-style='currentStyle'>

scope.currentStyle = {
   "background": "-moz-linear-gradient(top, " + colorFrom + " 0%, " + colorTo + " 100%)",
   "background": "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, " + colorFrom + "), color-stop(100%," + colorTo + "))",
   "background": "-webkit-linear-gradient(top,  " + colorFrom + " 0%," + colorTo + " 100%)",
   "background": "-o-linear-gradient(top,  " + colorFrom + " 0%," + colorTo + " 100%)",
   "background": "-ms-linear-gradient(top,  " + colorFrom + " 0%," + colorTo + " 100%)",
   "background": "linear-gradient(to bottom,  " + colorFrom + " 0%," + colorTo + " 100%)"
}
```

if seems that having javascript object with the same named keys is wrong, isn't it?
Then how do I make a gradient style?

upd: I don't know, maybe there's nothing wrong with a javascript object like this (works in my browser), but coffeescript compiler complaining about code like this, says: Multiple object literal properties named ""background""

Comment: Works fine in coffeescript, in that it doesn't complain. Of course you cannot have the same key multiple times.

Comment: well, yes in the latest it does, the thing is my colleagues are using a VS extension that uses older compiler, and it does complain

Comment: I deal with it by using `ng-class` instead :)

Comment: yeah but if you noticed it's a computed style, color values changing in runtime. Can't stick something like that into .css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you avoided the ngStyle directive and just used:

```
<div style='{{currentStyle}}'></div>
```

That way you could create your style declaration as a string in plain CSS.

```
$scope.currentStyle = "background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, " + colorFrom + " 0%, " + colorTo + " 100%);"
[etc....]
```

Comment: I know it's not as elegant. If you wanted something prettier maybe write a special directive to handle your gradient code?

Comment: yeah, you right, probably it's better to have a directive, if I find myself using the same thing again, I will definitely turn it into a directive